# Compare 2 ActiveDirectory properties using Powershell

Tags: powershell, active-directory, compare

My Goal is to List all ADusers where the property proxyAddresses does **not** contain the value from the mail property.

My first step is to get all users that have both values filled with:

```
$ADUser = Get-ADUser -Properties Name,Mail,proxyAddresses -Filter {proxyAddresses -like '*' -and mail -like '*'}
```

then i try to run it trough a foreach loop with an integrated if statement

```
$result = foreach ($User in $ADUser){
$proxystring = $User.proxyAddresses
    $Mailstring = $User.Mail

    $Mailstring = $Mailstring.ToString()
                
    if ($proxystring -contains '*$Mailstring*'){

    Write-Host 'läuft'
    }
    
    else{
    
    Write-Output($User).Name

    }
}
```

in the if statement i tried

```
if ($proxystring -contains '*$Mailstring*')
if ($proxystring -contains $Mailstring)
if ($proxystring -like $Mailstring)
if (($proxystring).contains($Mailstring))
```

As in the mainpart of the Code seen, I also tried to pass it to a string because i thought the format might be a problem.

Everywhere i looked a variable only gets matched with a string, not with other variables.

If anyone happens to know what my mistake is i would be grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to remove the preceding `SMTP:` / `smtp:` from each address in [`proxyAddresses`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adschema/a-proxyaddresses) for this to work properly:

```
$result = :outer foreach ($User in $ADUser){
    foreach($address in $user.proxyAddresses) {
        # remove the leading `smtp:` from each address
        $mail = $address -replace '^smtp:'
        # and compare, if the user's mail was in the `proxyAddresses` array
        if($mail -eq $User.mail) {
            # there is no need to keep checking, we can skip this user
            # and go next
            continue outer
        }
    }
    # if the user's `mail` wasn't found in the `proxyAddresses` array
    # output this user
    $user
}
```

You could also use [`-notcontains`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7.2#containment-operators) to simplify the above code a lot but this requires prepending `smtp:` to user's `mail` attribute:

```
$result = foreach ($User in $ADUser){
    if($user.proxyAddresses -notcontains ('smtp:' + $user.mail)) {
        $User
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah thank you that seems to work, do you know why he cant compare the values when proxyAddresses include SMTP:?

Comment: @Trippin see my update. basically the methods you're using don't work because the `mail` attribute is just an email address and each element in `proxyAddresses` are email addresses with `smtp:` in the beginning so you're not comparing apples to apples